# Underfitting because of Image Augmentation or Noise?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I created the following model:

```
def create_model(input_shape = (224, 224, 3)):
    input_img = Input(shape=input_shape)
    model = efnB0_model (input_img)
    backbone = Flatten() (model)

    branches = []
    for i in range(7):
            branches.append(backbone)
            branches[i] = Dense(360, activation = "relu", name="branch_"+str(i)+"_Dense_16000")(branches[i])
            branches[i] = Dense(128, activation = "relu", name="branch_"+str(i)+"_Dense_128")(branches[i])
            branches[i] = Dense(35, activation = "softmax", name="branch_"+str(i)+"_output")(branches[i])
        
    output = Concatenate(axis=1)(branches)
    output = Reshape((7, 35))(output)
    model = Model(input_img, output)

    return model
```

It is the bottom architecture of the `EfficientNet` with `ImageNet` weights (link: https://keras.io/api/applications/efficientnet/#efficientnetb0-function) and a customized top to recognize license plates of the shape `(7, 35)`. 7 is the max number of characters on a license plate and 35 the possible characters.

I created a DataGenerator to feed batches of data to my model:

```
class DataGenerator(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return math.ceil(len(self.x) / self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_x = [imread(file_name) for file_name in batch_x]
        batch_x = np.array(batch_x)
        batch_x = batch_x * 1./255
        batch_y = self.y[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_y = np.array(batch_y)

        return batch_x, batch_y
```

I compiled the model:

```
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

And used fit_generator:

```
model.fit_generator(generator=training_generator,
                    validation_data=validation_generator,
                    steps_per_epoch = num_train_samples // 16,
                    validation_steps = num_val_samples // 16,
                    epochs = 20, workers=6, use_multiprocessing=True)
```

I got the following values for accuracy on 10.000 training images and 2000 validation images:
[image: without imgaug]

So, there are huge differences between training and validation accuracy. I guess it is due to overfitting because of small data volume and a complex model.

After that, I constructed a `DataGenerator` which adds Gaussian Noise to the images:

```
class DataGenerator_aug(Sequence):

    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return math.ceil(len(self.x) / self.batch_size)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_x = np.array([resize(imread(file_name), (224, 224)) for file_name in batch_x])
        batch_x = batch_x.astype(np.uint8)
        aug = iaa.AdditiveGaussianNoise(0.5, scale=(0, 0.2*255))
        batch_x = aug(images=batch_x)
        batch_x = batch_x * 1./255

        

        batch_y = self.y[idx*self.batch_size : (idx + 1)*self.batch_size]
        batch_y = np.array(batch_y)

        return batch_x, batch_y
```

I used the same code to compile and fit the model and got this results:

[image: imgaug]

This result differs significantly from the results before. This must be due to the noise. That means, that the model underfits because of the noise, correct? What would you do in this case to solve the overfitting and underfitting issues?

Comment: I can't see any problem at a glance, therefore you could do some changes in your `fit_generator` method. Maybe, try increasing your batch size. For instance: `steps_per_epoch = num_train_samples // 256`

Comment: But do you think increasing the batch size will help to reduce the issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are adding noise, then, the network is also trying to find the patterns in the noise you have added and the data you already had. You made the work harder for the network which is the reason for these new results.

Usually, in such cases, these are the things you should do:

1. Use dropout.
2. Use data augmentation (crop, flip, shear, rotate).

Comment: Okay, dropout is added by default to the network when using EfficientNet. So, I think, it is not necessary to add additional dropout. Regarding data augmentation, I think there are mainly two techniques which could make sense with regards on the input data which are license plates: 1. rotation (but a slighter one). 2. changing the color space. I think cropping, flipping, shearing and a to strong rotation would corrupt the images and would make it impossible for the network to recognize the images correctly, correct?

Comment: If you can increase dropout that would be great. Also, in regards to shearing and cropping, there should not be any issues. Did you try anything?

Comment: I tried Dropout2d https://imgaug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/overview/arithmetic.html#dropout2d and Rotate https://imgaug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/overview/geometric.html#rotate instead of Gaussian Noise but the results still remain the same.... Would you try Gaussian Noise and one other option?

Comment: Use it without Gaussian noise.

Comment: Ok, I did that, but as mentioned above, I still get poor results. Do you think the model is not adequate?